# Django static files not found in production 1.2

Tags: python, django, django-static

My code is working fine in the testing environment (DEBUG=TRUE) but when I switch to DEBUG=FALSE, static files are not being loaded.

**To run the application I follow**:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
python3 manage.py runserver
```

**settings.py**:

```
from pathlib import Path, os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-z$w^9$+no7vh2hbu#d6j7b3rx!+m=ombxy9=h%u&cr_=0v)ojv'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.vercel.app', '.alisolanki.com', '.now.sh']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sentiment_analysis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sentiment_analysis.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Added by me
import os
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')
```

Here, the `python3 manage.py collectstatic` command correctly fetches my static files and stores it to staticfiles_build/static. However none of my static files are being loaded in production.

Answer (score 0):

> However none of my static files are being loaded in production.

do you mean in templates if so you need to load them with `{% load static %}` template tag

if not... depending on your server you need to configure it to server static files [how to do this with Apache and mod_wsgi.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

you can read more about [How to deploy static files - django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)